# Apache karaf not starting as systemd service in RHEL

Tags: osgi, systemd, apache-karaf, rhel7

I have recently come across into an issue in which i have apache karaf osgi container with features , i have installed this apache karaf as systemd service,

After starting and stoping the service ,the file `/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` getting overwritten. But it happens only sometimes. And due to this the karaf is not starting

We cannot replicate that situation, but sometime it happens.
Any idea what could be reason.
While starting and stoping will this file is getting modified?

Is it due to some race conditions or some hard kill 9 is happening while stopping service. But it not everytime.
I am just going through the apache karaf src code.
Didn't find any valid reason for this behaviour.
Its apache karaf 4.2.16 ,java 8 and rhel 7.